# Error updating pg gem from 0.17.0 to 0.17.1 for Mac OS X 10.9.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, postgresql, pg

Just did a simple `bundle update` and got an annoying error related to the `pg` gem for PostgreSQL. I don't have PostgreSQL installed on my system (unless it's automatically installed for Mac OS X 10.9.1). This has never been an issue before. Any ideas?

```
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4) 
Using jquery-rails-cdn (1.0.1) 
Installing liquid (2.6.1) 
Using paperclip (3.5.2) 
Installing pg (0.17.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@ucode/gems/pg-0.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@ucode/gems/pg-0.17.1/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.


$ gem list pg

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

pg (0.17.0, 0.16.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.0, 0.14.1)
```

***UPDATE***: as requested, this is my `mkmf.log` file

```
find_executable: checking for pg_config... -------------------- no

--------------------

find_header: checking for libpq-fe.h... -------------------- no

"/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -o conftest -I/Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0 -I/Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/Users/mpapis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib -L. -L/Users/mpapis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib     -lruby.1.9.1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mpapis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib'
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */

"/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -E -I/Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0 -I/Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/Users/mpapis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include -fno-common -pipe  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: 'libpq-fe.h' file not found
#include <libpq-fe.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
/* end */

--------------------
```

***UPDATE 2***: The only mention of `pg` in my `Gemfile` is here:

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Comment: provide your `mkmf.log`

Comment: @majioa - I added it to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to install [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/).

Then do:

```
$ gem install pg -v '0.17.1' && bundle update
```

Edit:  Do not forget to [add the relevant directories into your `PATH`](http://postgresapp.com/documentation#toc_1).

Comment: Do I really need to install Postgres? I never had to before. I don't use Postgres on my Mac, only when I push out my app to Heroku.

Comment: Apparently the `pg` gem has dependencies to native libraries. Is your `pg` gem in the `:production` group in your Gemfile? Can you paste your Gemfile actually?

Comment: `pg` is in my `:production` group. I pasted that portion, the only place the word 'pg' appears in my `Gemfile`.

Comment: You're telling bundler to update *all* your gems, therefore you need to update `pg` too. If you want to update `pg` you *have* to have postgres installed.

Comment: Note that you must follow the instructions for Postgres.app to add its binaries (including `pg_config`) to the `PATH` if you're going to use it.

Comment: I installed Postgres.app by simply dragging it into my Applications folder and then running it (as per instructions on website). I still get an error when installing the `pg` gem.

Comment: Propably you haven't added it to your `PATH`: PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH". Refer to: http://postgresapp.com/documentation#toc_1

Comment: Yes that was it @Agis, I actually did add it to my path, but the app is called Postgres93.app, not Postgres.app as the documentation suggests to add to your path.

Answer (score 1):

try reinstall `pg` gem `gem install pg --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config`

I recomended install this app [Postgres](http://postgresapp.com/)
and install gem:

`env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config`

Answer (score 0):

check this blog this guy have a details explanation of how to do this

http://wikimatze.de/installing-postgresql-gem-under-ubuntu-and-mac.html

Answer (score 0):

Newbie here.  I had the same error after doing a git clean -xdf.  For some reason after I did this I could not start my local rails server nor would bundle install / update work giving the same pg gem errors.  It was basically ignoring the following in my gemfile:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

I was able to fix things by running the following line again.  I guess it's set this back to default as I can now also just use bundle install when making updates.

```
bundle install --without production
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This *does* provide a potential solution... as long as it actually works for the O/P